# Active tag on MVC 4 layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC 4 (Razor).
My HTML design contains a menu that (using some sort of javascript component),
I am looking for a smart way to mark the menu with what page am I currently on.

```
  <li class="glyphicons home currentScroll active"><a href="index.html?lang=en"><i></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
  <li class="glyphicons charts"> <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Campaigns")"><i></i><span>Campaigns</span></a> </li>
  <li class="glyphicons sort">  @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
  <li class="glyphicons picture"> <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
```

As you see the active `li` is marked, if I want to use this menu in the `_layout.cshtml` page, how can I change the Active mark according to the page I am currently loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this:

```
var controller = (string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
var action = (string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

For each menu item check for equals menu controller and current controller (and action, may be)